# How can I programmatically call Ubuntu's on screen keyboard in gtk/python?

Tags: keyboard, python, gtk

I'm programming my interfaces using gtk python and displaying them in Udoo Neo screen without having physical keyboard.

I want the keyboard to be displayed whenever I have a field to be filled. However, I dont want to use the Tkinter library.

Is there an easy way to have a keyboard on screen?

Comment: How are you using gtk in python?

Comment: I m combining glade with python

Comment: Would the [onboard](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=onboard&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package be of use to you?

Comment: ***Close voters***: This question is on how to code calling the keyboard on focus in ***On Ubuntu***.  It is about coding for Ubuntu. On topic imho.

Comment: Hi Arwa, posted my answer. Please mention if all is clear (or not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Calling the onboard keyboard on focus of a field

You can call any command on focus in/out by using:

```
field.connect('focus-in-event', self.focus_in)
```

or:

```
field.connect('focus-out-event', self.focus_out)
```

where `focus_in()` and `focus_out()` are your functions, called on focus in or out.

#### An example

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import signal
import subprocess

class CallKeyboardTest:

    def __init__(self):
        
        # window definition
        window = Gtk.Window(title="Test 123")
        window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        # maingrid
        maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
        maingrid.set_border_width(12)
        window.add(maingrid)
        # two different fields, one is calling the keyboard, the other isn't
        testfield = Gtk.Entry()
        testfield.connect('focus-in-event', self.focus_in)
        testfield.connect('focus-out-event', self.focus_out)
        otherfield = Gtk.Entry()
        maingrid.attach(testfield, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        maingrid.attach(otherfield, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        window.show_all()
        Gtk.main()
        
    def focus_out(self, entry, event):
        subprocess.Popen(["pkill", "onboard"])

    def focus_in(self, entry, event):
        subprocess.Popen("onboard")

    def stop_prefs(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CallKeyboardTest()
```

On the example above, the on screen keyboard will be called if the field "testfield" gets focussed, on focus out (or focussing on the "otherfield"), the on screen keyboard will disappear.

*Call the keyboard on focus*

[image]

*Close the keyboard on focus out*

[image]

#### Note

The onboard keyboard has a number of option, like layout, position, log-learning, size etc. See `man onboard`

Comment: It worked on my ubuntu laptop, however on my Udoo Neo screen it doesn't+ it raises a child exception error

Comment: @ArwaMoath Please post the exact and full error message.

Comment: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/udooer/Desktop/SaedRobot/ScanTape.py", line 58, in focus_in
    subprocess.Popen("onboard")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @ArwaMoath the code is python3. Run it with `python3 /path/to/script.py` it can be altered to run on python2 though. Btw, this is on Ubuntu?

Comment: How can I alter it to run on python 2.7, yes its ubuntu

Comment: @ArwaMoath I didn't use python2 for quite a while, need to check, I will if I get home. I am on mobile atm. Did you try on python3?

Comment: No, my whole program works on python 2.7

Comment: @ArwaMoath Ha, yes, but I mean the snippet :)

Comment: What do you by snippet, I m so novice, sorry

Comment: @ArwaMoath no worries :). I mean the code example in the answer, does it work when run with python3?

Comment: It didnt work in python3 it did work in my laptop 2.7 but my udoo neo screen didnt work

Comment: @ArwaMoath Silly question, but how did you exactly run it (python3), and what is your Ubuntu version? On Budgie for example, onboard (on screen keyboard) is not installed by default.

Comment: Thanks! I installed onboard and it worked .. I have to adjust its position though.  Thanks again

Comment: @ArwaMoath You mean it works on python2? Do you still need the code to be adapted?

Comment: The problem is the keyboard takes 3 secs to appear

Comment: Thanks, it is faster on my system, but we might be able to hide/show the keyboard. Will try if I get home.

Comment: I tried a command to change the size+position but it doesn't work. I changed it manually but it resets to the default whenever i press one of the keyboard's buttons